# Flask-Admin batch action with form

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have a `Flask` application with `Flask-SQLAlchemy` and `Flask-Admin`.

I would like to perform a batch action, but with form. For example I would like to set a same text value to the form attributed, but this value is entered by the user.

I saw [documentation for batch actions](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/#customizing-batch-actions), but it has example only for predefined data.

Is it possible, or maybe there's some workaround for this?

Answer (score 4):

The way I achieve this is to do an internal POST in the `@action` method.

```
class AddressView(AdminView):

    # ... ....

    @action('merge', 'Merge', 'Are you sure you want to merge selected addresses?')
    def action_merge(self, ids):

        if len(ids) < 2:
            flash("Two or more addresses need to be selected before merging")
            return

        return_url = request.referrer
        return redirect(url_for('mergeaddresses.index', return_url=return_url), code=307)
```

Then define two routes, one for the internal post and then one to receive the submit POST from the form that receives the user's input data (`MergeAddressForm` in the case below).

In the example below I happen to be using a Flask-Admin BaseView to handle the routes. Note how the original checked IDs in the flask-admin list view are retrieved and then stored in the form as an encoded comma delimited list hidden field and likewise the `return_url` back to the flask-admin list view.

```
class MergeAddressesView(BaseView):

    form_base_class = BaseForm

    def __init__(self, name=None, category=None,
                 endpoint=None, url=None,
                 template='admin/index.html',
                 menu_class_name=None,
                 menu_icon_type=None,
                 menu_icon_value=None):
        super(MergeAddressesView, self).__init__(name,
                                             category,
                                             endpoint,
                                             url or '/admin',
                                             'static',
                                             menu_class_name=menu_class_name,
                                             menu_icon_type=menu_icon_type,
                                             menu_icon_value=menu_icon_value)
        self._template = template

    def is_visible(self):
        return False

    @expose('/', methods=['POST'])
    def index(self):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # get the original checked id's
            ids = request.form.getlist('rowid')

            merge_form = MergeAddressForm()
            merge_form.process()
            joined_ids = ','.join(ids)
            encoded = base64.b64encode(joined_ids)
            merge_form.ids.data = encoded
            _return_url = request.args['return_url']
            merge_form.return_url.data = _return_url
            self._template_args['form'] = merge_form
            self._template_args['cancel_url'] = _return_url
            return self.render(self._template)

    @expose('/merge', methods=['POST'])
    def merge(self):

        if request.method == 'POST':
            merge_form = MergeAddressForm(selection_choices=[])
            decoded = base64.b64decode(merge_form.ids.data)
            ids = decoded.split(',')
            # do the merging
            address_merger = AddressMerger(ids=ids, primary_id=merge_form.primary_address.data)
            address_merger.merge()
            # return to the original flask-admin list view
            return redirect(merge_form.return_url.data)
```

My template for the user input form looks something like below. Note the action url.

```
{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block body %}
    <h3>{{ admin_view.name|title }}</h3>
    <form role="form" action="{{ url_for('mergeaddresses.merge') }}" method="post" name="form">

        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

        {{ wtf.form_errors(form) }}

        {{ wtf.form_field(form.primary_address) }}

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Merge</button>
        <a href="{{ cancel_url }}" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Cancel</a>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```